# How can i add localization to a maven changes report?

Tags: localization, maven-3

I am use maven 3.0.3 with *maven-changes-plugin* to generate an changes report for my maven project - in english and german. There is a *changes.xml* found by the *maven-changes-plugin*. Additional there is a configured *maven-site-plugin* to support locales en,de. All reports works fine - all titles are correct localized. But how could i localize the content of reports?

The *maven-changes-plugin* is using only the onest *changes.xml* for input. No other changes_de.xml* or *de/changes.xml* will be used. So i think the correct way is to localize by property files. But where is the correct place for it (*basedir* or *src/main/resources/* or *src/site/resources*)? What is the correct name for the property files -
changes_de.xml, changes-report_de.html.properties, changes-report_de.properties ...?

Is any localization supported by the *maven-changes-plugin* at now?

Comment: Maybe we could use a trick (alternate location for each language and defining it in the excecution phase plugin configuration):
http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-changes-plugin-2.6/examples/alternate-changes-xml-location.html

Answer (score 1):

Some maven reports have been localized. I think changes plugin is one of those (at least for fr and de). You should check 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/localization.html and
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/l10n-status.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The maven-changes-plugin was localized. But the localization changed only the title's, the key word's like *release* and so on. But it does not change the content (the words which i put between the report tags). This could required a second file or a special property which is unknow to me.
I have scanned the sources, the content will be computed via ResourceBundles. But there is no property for the content parts or i have overlooked it.